# Cleaner way to register collections with Unity 3

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I usually use Autofac but this client requires we use Unity on their project.  The ability to register by matching interface is nice and is saving some time from when I had to use version 2.  I'm still finding collections to be a bit combersome.  Is there an technique that would allow me to be able to add new IPrePopulationModule instances without having to register them individually like I have to below?

```
    container.RegisterType<IPrePopulationModule, PopulateGenders>("PopulateGenders", new PerHttpRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IPrePopulationModule, PopulateOrigins>("PopulateOrigins", new PerHttpRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IPrePopulationModule, PopulateRelationshipTypes>("PopulateRelationshipTypes", new PerHttpRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IPrePopulationModule, PopulateRepresentationTypes>("PopulateRepresentationTypes", new PerHttpRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IPrePopulationModule, PopulateRuleSets>("PopulateRuleSets", new PerHttpRequestLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<IPrePopulationModule>, IPrePopulationModule[]>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity 3 added [registration by convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463.aspx#sec23) to handle cases like this...

```
//There's other options for each parameter (and you can supply your own custom options)
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().
        Where(type => typeof(IPrePopulationModule).IsAssignableFrom(type)),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfacesInSameAssembly,
    WithName.TypeName,
    type => new PerHttpRequestLifetimeManager());
```